# Find/Count all tables in the document's body (including all nested tables of all levels)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to count all of the tables in the main body of a document, including any nested tables existing at any given level.

So far, I've managed to count the tables up to 2 levels deep of nested tables, that is:

```
Level 0    Main table
Level 1       Nested tables
Level 2          Nested tables
```

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
Sub CountTables()
Dim mainTable As Word.Table
Dim nestedTable1 As Word.Table
Dim nestedTable2 As Word.Table
Dim n As Long
Dim ns As Long
Dim ns2 As Long
Dim NumOfTbl As Long

For Each mainTable In ActiveDocument.Tables

    n = n + 1
    NumOfTbl = NumOfTbl + 1
    Debug.Print "------ Table " & n & " ------"

        'nested level 1
        ns = 0
        For Each nestedTable1 In mainTable.Tables
            ns = ns + 1
            NumOfTbl = NumOfTbl + 1
            Debug.Print "Nested Table " & n & "." & ns

                'nested level 2
                ns2 = 0
                For Each nestedTable2 In nestedTable1.Tables
                    ns2 = ns2 + 1
                    NumOfTbl = NumOfTbl + 1
                    Debug.Print "Nested Table " & n & "." & ns & "." & ns2
                    Next nestedTable2

            Next nestedTable1
    Next mainTable

Debug.Print vbNewLine & "Total number of tables: " & NumOfTbl

End Sub
```

As can be seen, the code is pretty limited as it is hard-coded to find up to the second level of nested tables. Of course, if there are even deeper nested tables - these will be overlooked.

So, a structure like the one below will completely ignore levels 3 onward:

```
Level 0    Main table
Level 1       Nested tables
Level 2          Nested tables
Level 3             Nested tables
.
..
...
```

I can't figure out how I can detect any level a table might be in without hard-codeding a unique variable as I did (Dim nestedTable1..) in order to loop though nested tables within nested tables.

How can I loop through all nested levels indefinetly, to absolutely get all nested tables, all the way down?

Comment: One solution I can imagine is using a do while loop along with recursion, where you pass each parent table as an argument. Maybe there are simpler solutions I can't immediately think of. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question...

The following works for me and bases on recursive calling of a procedure. In order to keep track of each table and its properties, a `Type` is declared named `WordTable`. For each table, an instance of `WordTable` is created and assigned to an array, also of this type.

The Type can hold anything that's wanted/needed, even a `Table` object that points to the table. Here, there's the position in the document, the nesting level (0 when not nested), the row and column indexes of the *parent table* (if a nested table, otherwise 0), as well as the row and column counts of the table. I found these handy for checking/identifying which table was which Index.

```
Option Explicit

Type WordTable
    Index As Long           'Table position in document
    NestingLevel As Long    'Nesting level calculated from main
    RowIndex As Long        'Row index in parent table
    ColIndex As Long        'Column index in parent table
    RowCount As Long        'Number of rows in table
    ColCount As Long        'Number of columns in table
End Type
```

The procedure `GetAllTablesInDocument` declares a `Range` object set to the entire document as the starting point for looping the tables. The array for the `WordTable` type is also declared as well as a counter for the array (set to -1 initially, will be incremented in the loop).

At the end, it prints out the `Type` information to the VBA Editor Immediate Window.

```
Sub GetAllTablesInDocument()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim aTables() As WordTable
    Dim tblCounter As Long

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.content
    tblCounter = -1

    GetAllTablesInRange rng, tblCounter, aTables, False

    For tblCounter = LBound(aTables) To UBound(aTables)
        Debug.Print aTables(tblCounter).Index, aTables(tblCounter).NestingLevel, _
           aTables(tblCounter).RowIndex, aTables(tblCounter).ColIndex, _
           aTables(tblCounter).RowCount, aTables(tblCounter).ColCount
    Next
    Debug.Print "Number of tables: " & aTables(UBound(aTables)).Index
End Sub
```

`GetAllTablesInRange` loops the tables at the `Range` level passed to it. This is the recursive part: it's called for the tables and the main level as well as for nested tables. The `Range`, the counter for the array and the array are passed to it `By Ref` so that they maintain state (don't restart when the procedure is called again).

There's also the parameter `nestedCall` which is used when the procedure is called for a nested table. It's used to get the row and column index of the parent table.

The part that triggers the recursiveness is `If tbl.Tables.Count > 0 Then` - if the table has tables, then it has nested tables. In this case, `GetTablesInTable` is called, which loops the nested table(s). And if the nested table contains nested tables, it's called again... And so on until all levels have been processed.

```
Function GetAllTablesInRange(ByRef rng As Word.Range, _
  ByRef tblCounter As Long, _
  ByRef aTables() As WordTable, nestedCall As Boolean)
    'Dim aTAbles() As WordTable
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim t As WordTable
    Dim rngTable As Word.Range

    For Each tbl In rng.Tables
        tblCounter = tblCounter + 1
        ReDim Preserve aTables(tblCounter)
        t.Index = tblCounter + 1
        t.NestingLevel = tbl.NestingLevel
        t.RowCount = tbl.Rows.Count
        t.ColCount = tbl.Columns.Count
        If nestedCall Then
            Set rngTable = tbl.Range
            rngTable.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            t.RowIndex = rngTable.Rows(1).Index
            t.ColIndex = rngTable.Columns(1).Index
        Else
            t.RowIndex = 0
            t.ColIndex = 0
        End If
        aTables(tblCounter) = t
        If tbl.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            GetTablesInTable tbl, tblCounter, aTables()
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function GetTablesInTable(tbl As Word.Table, _
  ByRef tblCounter As Long, _
  ByRef aTables() As WordTable) 'As WordTable()

    Dim nestedTable As Word.Table

    For Each nestedTable In tbl.Tables
        GetAllTablesInRange nestedTable.Range, tblCounter, aTables(), True
    Next
End Function
```

Note: Some of the `WordTable` Type information will not work (cause errors) if the "parent table" of a nested table contains merged cells (Row and Column index).

Comment: One thing i ran into while testing it: it fails if one of the tables have any merged cells - i get error 5992: "Cannot access individual column in this collection because the table has mixed cell widths."

If I use On Error and identify that specific error# and tell VBA to ignor it specificaly - is it an ok solution? I need to dig a little bit into the code to address the issue from within, not using an error handler...

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? Note that I didn't test merged cells - that didn't seem to be a requirement in the original question. It may well be something you don't need (part of the `WordTable` Type that I was using for checking how accurate the code was)?

Comment: You are right, merged cells wasn't a requierment (I ran into the issue while running the code on one of the docs which happened to have merged cells). 

The error shows up if a nested table is within a merged cell - It fails to get the index of rngle.RowsTab(1).Index (a merged cell) into t.RowIndex. 

As you pointed out, I removed the use of Row and Column indexes and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I've added a note to the answer warning about those property calls when working with tables containing merged cells.